# How do you use malloc to allocate space for an array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I'm currently working on dynamically allocating my array of structures and I'm unsure how to continue. This is my structure:

```
struct Word_setup 
{
    char word[M];
    int count;
} phrase[N];
```

I know `malloc` returns a pointer to a block of memory, but I'm not sure how this works when it comes to an array of structures.
If anyone could please clarify that would be much appreciated!

Comment: How would you do it for a simpler array, like an array of ints?  It's no different.

Comment: Perhaps `size_t N = 5; struct Word_setup *phrase = malloc(N * sizeof *phrase);`

Comment: @chux Thats what I was going to do, I need to reallocate memory as the program progresses. I realize that probably should have been my question....

Answer (score 1):

Probably you meant:

```
struct Word_setup {
    char word[M];
    int count;
};
```

It's a good idea to avoid defining variables in the same line as a struct definition anyway, to help with code readability.

Then you can allocate an array of these:

```
int main()
{
    struct Word_setup *phrase = malloc(N * sizeof *phrase);

    // use phrases[x] where 0 <= x < N

    phrase = realloc(phrase, (N+5) * sizeof *phrase);

    // now can go up to phrases[N+4]

    free(phrase);
}
```

Of course you should check for failure and abort the program if `malloc` or `realloc` returns `NULL`.

---

If you also want to dynamically allocate each string inside the word then there are a few options; the simplest one to understand is to change `char word[M]` to `char *word;` and each time you allocate a phrase, write `the_phrase.word = malloc(some_number);` .  If you allocate an array of words you'll need to loop through doing that for each word.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "where x < N" || Do you mean that N represents the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @NicolasDiken yes, the same N that appears in the `malloc` expression

Comment: Alright thats what I assumed. Now the issue is using `realloc` to reallocate the space dynamically. I'm not 100% sure about the syntax, so I keep getting silly errors. This is what I tried: `phrase = realloc(phrase, SIZE * i);` but I got an error saying that I'm convering a `void pointer` to type `struct Word_setup`. Which is clear, but I'm unsure how to go about changing this.

Comment: @NicolasDiken that doesn't make much sense, compare your `realloc` line with your `malloc` line to see what you've done differently. I'll update my code with an example.

Comment: Oddly enough, I didnt see this other error before. I get the same error for the `struct Word_setup *phrase = malloc(N * sizeof *phrases);` line of my code O.o

Comment: If the error talks about `struct Word_setup *`  then the problem is that you are using a C++ compiler to compile C code, and the solution is that you should use a C compiler instead . (for most compiler suites this just means making sure the file is called `.c`)

Comment: Haha I'm not that new to programming. I'm currently using GCC, which works for both C and C++.

Comment: This is the exact error I'm getting: `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Word_setup*' [-fpermissive]
 struct Word_setup *phrase = malloc(sizeof(*phrase));`

Comment: @NicolasDiken you are using a C++ compiler when you should be using a C compiler. Can you show the commandline you are passing to gcc ?

Comment: gcc proj4.c -o proj4.exe \n proj4.exe

Comment: Are you sure it is `proj4.c` and not `proj4.C` ?  (gcc autodetects upper-case `C` to mean c++).  In any case you can force C compilation by writing `gcc -x c proj4.c -o proj4.exe`.  Also I recommend using `-Wall -pedantic` as then you get all the diagnostics that the C standard requires.

Comment: I use lowercase c when compiling. When I use: `gcc -x c proj4.c -o proj4.exe` to compile, cmd gives me this error: `initializer element is not constant struct Word_setup *phrase = malloc(SIZE)`. And has an arrow pointing to "W". If I compile it the same way I was before I get the same exact error.

Comment: @NicolasDiken have you placed that code outside of a function?

Comment: in any case, post a new question with the code you are compiling copy-pasted; how to operate your compiler is really nothing to do with the question you originally asked on this thread

Comment: Yes it's outside of my main function. But I just moved it inside of the `main` function, and I'm still getting the same error of "invalid conversion". Would it be possible for us to communicate through some other form of social media, reddit persay?

Comment: No, just post a new question with your exact code (and compilation command) . The 'invalid conversion' error comes from invoking your compiler in C++ mode , assuming you have described your code correctly. (Exact code is much better than a description of code)

Comment: Notes:1) could use `size_t N = 0; struct Word_setup *phrase = NULL; ... N = 5; phrase = realloc(phrase, N * sizeof *phrase);`  IOWs `malloc()` is not needed.  2) If `N == 0` then should `malloc(N * sizeof *phrase)` return `NULL`, that does not necessarily mean out-of-memory (code need not abort).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `N` and `M` is a compile-time known constants. Then just use `sizeof`, .e.g.

```
 struct Word_setup*ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Word_setup)*N);
```

Maybe you want a [flexible array member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). Then, it should always be the *last* member of your `struct`, e.g.

```
  struct Word_setup {
     int count;
     unsigned size;
     char word[]; // of size+1 dimension
  };
```

Of course it is meaningless to have an array  of flexibly sized structures -you need an array of pointers to them.

Comment: What I want in this case, is a flexible array of structures. So the array can grow as it reads more items into itself.

Comment: Why not a flexible array of pointers to flexible `struct`-s? It looks like you should do that !

Comment: The goal of the overall program is to read a file, and output the word with the max appearances, as well as the number of appearances. I did this by creating an array of structures, where each structure stores the word, as well as the count. Now my issue is that I need to make this array dynamically changing as more words get scanned.